# MongDB limit(1) it return result array empty

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, limit

I have use libraries php mongodb with codeigniter when I use `limit(1)` it return result array empty but when I use `limit(2)` or `limit(n)` the return result is correct to me I don know why?

Below is my code to use:

```
> $resutl = $this->mongo_db->limit(1)->get('UserProfile');
```

Info Library:

```
/**  
* CodeIgniter MongoDB Active Record Library  
*  
* A library to interface with the NoSQL database MongoDB. For more information see mongodb.org  
*  
* @package      CodeIgniter  
* @author       Alex Bilbie   
* @copyright    Copyright (c) 2010, Alex Bilbie.  
* @license      http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php  
* @link         http://alexbilbie.com  
* @version      Version 0.5.2  
*  
* Thanks to Kyle Dye (kyledye.com), Nick Jackson (nickjackson.me), Mikhail Kozlov (mikhailkozlov.com) and Phil Sturgeon (philsturgeon.co.uk) for additional help  
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its work for you or not you will get some idea about it thought for sure.

```
$links = $this->mongo_db
        ->where(array(
            'status' => 1,
            'siteid' => 1
        ))->where_lt('publishedtime', $start)->order_by(array('publishedtime'=>'desc'))
        ->limit(10)->get('links');
```

OR

```
$query = $this->CI->cimongo->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));
```